# AngularJS : How to update select option value when ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-model

I have a Working **Select Option** with few values which are **filtering** data for search.

Now i need few links beside as **Sidebar** which is helpfull to directly **click and change** the above **Select Options**

Please refer to this Link [Website Link](http://proconstruct.co.in/jsearch) i made.

---

**Login sample :**

> **User** : recobee@gmail.com
>
> **Pass** : kishore

http://proconstruct.co.in/jsearch

---

**Javascript :**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var json = {
    "modules":
        <?php echo $qres; ?>
  };

  $scope.ocw = json;

  var allCategories = json.modules.map(function(item) {
    return item.designation
  });
  var filteredCategories = [];

  var allCities = json.modules.map(function(item) {
    return item.city
  });
  var filteredCities = [];


  allCategories.forEach(function(item) {
    if (filteredCategories.indexOf(item) < 0 && item) {
      filteredCategories.push(item);
    }
  });

  allCities.forEach(function(item) {
    if (filteredCities.indexOf(item) < 0 && item) {
      filteredCities.push(item);
    }
  });

  $scope.search = {
    designation: ""
  }
  $scope.search = {
    city: ""
  }

  $scope.categories = filteredCategories;

  $scope.updateFilter = function(value) {
    $scope.search.designation = value;
  }


  $scope.cities = filteredCities;
  $scope.updateFilter = function(value) {
    $scope.search.city = value;
  }

});
```

---

These are the links html :

```
<div  ng-repeat="designation in categories ">
    <a ng-click="updateFilter(search.designation)"> {{designation}}</a>
</div>
```

This is the Selection which is working and has to react by links :

```
<select ng-model="search.designation">
    <option value="">All Categories</option>
    <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category}}">{{category}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look at your code I would try to change the following:

```
<div  ng-repeat="designation in categories ">
     <a ng-click="updateFilter(designation)"> {{designation}}</a>
</div>
```

The only thing I changed is the parameter for the updateFilter function.

**[ UPDATE ]**

You have also two functions with the same name: updateFilter

Try this as well:

```
$scope.search = {
    designation: "",
    city: ""
}

$scope.updateFilterDesignation = function(value) {
    $scope.search.designation = value;
}
$scope.updateFilterCity = function(value) {
    $scope.search.city = value;
}
```

So the link should do: ng-click="updateFilterDesignation(designation)"

This should work hopefully.

Comment: Tamy Thankyou very much its is working and can you help me about all results link to show All Categories :)

Comment: I think that when you click on Show All you need to call ng-click="updateFilterDesignation(null)" to reset $scope.search.designation value.

Comment: Tammy i made that change but it did't work and i have passed even "All Categories" replacing with null . value of select option was changing to All Categories but result not triggering.